# Correct way to use mySQL to contain data of 300 pages?

Tags: mysql

So I asked does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144014/does-mysql-update-add-a-row-if-it-doesnt-exist and I was told that I'm using columns incorrectly.

So I have 300 pages that need to fetch their data from a database. The content can be updated by going to a admin panel, selecting the page to update and altering the page content in a textarea with a WYSIWYG editor and simply pressing submit button. I created a test system with 8 columns which all have one row containing the page content. But this isn't the right way?

So, what would be the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I don't misunderstand you. I would put every page in one row. So just have a table with two columns `id` and `page_content`. That way you can delete, add or modify each row (page) with no problems.

Comment: Oh... Didn't even think about that :D Thanks :)